# My jquery .click(function) works only one time

Tags: jquery, performance

I am using .click() function to rotate a div when another div is clicked.
Here is the code i am using

jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '.plane' ).click(function( event ) {
        var change = document.getElementById('stage');
        change.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(-60deg)';
    }); 
});
```

html

```
<body>

    <div id="container" style="position:absolute" >
        <div id="stage" class="stage" >
            <div id="shape"  class="smallring cube backfaces">
                <div class="plane one" onclick="rotate()">
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:50%;">
                        <img id="rt" class="rt" src="1.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    C
                </div>
                <div class="plane two">
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:50%;">
                        <img class="rt" src="1.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    R
                </div>
                <div class="plane three">
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:50%;">
                        <img class="rt" src="1.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    E
                </div>
                <div class="plane four">
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:50%;">
                        <img class="rt" src="1.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    A
                </div>
                <div class="plane five">
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:50%;">
                        <img class="rt" src="1.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    T
                </div>
                <div class="plane six">
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:50%;">
                        <img class="rt" src="1.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    I
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

but the problem is that it works only the first time...i want the div to be rotated every time the particular div is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your markup

or try next

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.plane', function( event ) {
     var change = document.getElementById('stage');
    change.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(-60deg)';
});
```

To rotate try like this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.plane', function( event ) {
     var change = document.getElementById('stage');
     var webkitTransform = change.style.webkitTransform;

     var transformValue = webkitTransform.replace('rotateY(','').replace(')','');
     transformValue = parseInt(transformValue) || 0;

     var newValue = transformValue - 60;

     change.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(' + newValue +'deg)';
});
```

http://jsbin.com/dequqapatu/1/

Comment: i tried your function but it is also working only once

Comment: It work every time, but if your want to rotate block - you should change webkitTransform value

Comment: can you help me with controlling this rotation. like if i want to rotate it on both sides. have a look at awais.dpropk.com/hexagon
when i click on the front element i dont want any rotation , when left element is clicked i want it to be rotated on right and vise versa.
any idea how can i do that ?

Comment: which logic should switch rotate direction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70623/discussion-between-sheikh-awais-and-vasil-vanchuk).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway i suggest a 'cleaner' approach:

jQuery

```
$( '.plane' ).click(function() {
   $('#stage').toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

CSS:

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

example here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3pek6z5d/1/)